# (Re-)starting a systemd unit with user input on Ansible

Tags: systemd, ansible

Tools like [gocryptfs](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs#readme) have some advantages when they're used in combination with systemd, because dependency, status and permissions can easily be defined.

Since it needs a passphrase, it would either require a plain text file on the system or [a password via stdin](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs/issues/110#issuecomment-312419126) by using [`systemd-ask-password`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-ask-password.html).
The stdin variant is usually preferred since passphrases in plain text files have some disadvantages.

While [Ansible has a systemd module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) it doesn't seem to give a possibility to insert such arguments directly.

Thus I'm curious what the preferred way of handling service (re-)restarts with password inputs is when using Ansible.

Something that would do something like this pseudocode

```yaml
- name: Start GoCryptFs
  systemd:
    name: gocryptfs
    state: started
    daemon_reload: true
    args:
      stdin: "{{ gocryptfs_password }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure *gocryptfs* to use option *`-extpass CMD`*. Quoting from [*man gocryptfs*](https://man.archlinux.org/man/gocryptfs.1)

> *Use an external program (like ssh-askpass) for the password prompt. The program should return the password on stdout, a trailing newline is stripped by gocryptfs.*

For example, at the remote host create a script that returns the value of the variable *gocryptfs_password*

```yaml
shell> ssh admin@test_11 sudo cat /root/bin/gocryptfs-extpass.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo ${gocryptfs_password}
```

---

Automate this by Ansible too

```yaml
    - file:
        state: directory
        path: /root/bin
        owner: root
        group: wheel
        mode: '0755'
    - copy:
        dest: /root/bin/gocryptfs-extpass.sh
        owner: root
        group: wheel
        mode: '0700'
        content: |
          {{ '#' }}!/bin/sh
          echo ${gocryptfs_password}
```

---

Put the password into a file at the controller and [encrypt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#encrypting-content-with-ansible-vault) it

```yaml
shell> cat vault/test_11/gocryptfs_password.yml 
gocryptfs password at test_11
```

The playbook below reads the password from the file and sets the environment for the command

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_11
  vars:
    gocryptfs_password_file: "vault/{{ inventory_hostname }}/gocryptfs_password.yml"
  tasks:
    - command: /root/bin/gocryptfs-extpass.sh
      register: result
      environment:
        gocryptfs_password: "{{ lookup('file', gocryptfs_password_file) }}"
      no_log: true
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_11] => 
  result.stdout: gocryptfs password at test_11
```

If you manage to configure *gocryptfs* to use *`-extpass /root/bin/gocryptfs-extpass.sh`* the task below should do the job

```yaml
- name: User systemctl import environment gocryptfs_password
  command: systemctl --user import-environment gocryptfs_password

- name: Start GoCryptFs
  systemd:
    name: gocryptfs
    state: started
    daemon_reload: true
  environment:
    gocryptfs_password: "{{ lookup('file', gocryptfs_password_file) }}"
  no_log: true
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

**Notes**

- This scheme should pass most of the security requirements:

  - The encrypted password is stored remotely
  - The transfer of the password is encrypted
  - The scope of the password is limited to a single task
- Put the value of *gocryptfs_password* as appropriate. There are many options. For example, use [*passwordstore*](https://www.passwordstore.org/). Then, use *community.general.passwordstore* lookup plugin instead of *ansible.builtin.file*

```yaml
  environment:
    gocryptfs_password: "{{ lookup('community.general.passwordstore',
                                   'test_11/gocryptfs_password' }}"
```

- See

```
   shell> ansible-doc -t lookup community.general.passwordstore
```

- See [Pass an environment variable from current shell to a systemd unit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383433/pass-an-environment-variable-from-current-shell-to-a-systemd-unit) on how to pass the environment variable *gocryptfs_password* to *systemd*. (Credit @alexanderadam. See the comments below.)

```
   shell> systemctl --user import-environment gocryptfs_password
```

- See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization). Quoting: *"If it's your variable, lowercase it. If you export it, uppercase it. ... Use 'snake case' (all lowercase and underscores) for all variables that are scoped to a single script or a block."*

Comment: Ahoi Vladimir! Thank you so much for your fast response. I'm probably doing something wrong, though. It seems that the process isn't getting the environment variable. As far as I understood, systemd needs "PassEnvironment" directive but it doesn't seem to work. Or should it live somewhere else and not in the service file?

Comment: "PassEnvironment" directive shouldn't be needed. There is an [example](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/systemd_service.py#L139) on how to use *environment*. Have you tested the plain *command*? Make sure this is working first.

Comment: I created a minimal repository on GitHub to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/alexanderadam/systemd_unit_with_user_input if I set GOCRYPTFS_PASSWORD via export everything runs fine and the script echoes the variable content. But within the systemd unit the env variable is not visible.

Comment: I found the solution: it needed "systemctl --user import-environment GOCRYPTFS_PASSWORD" otherwise the environment variable isn't visible.

Comment: Cool! I updated the Notes and the example code. Does the *command* work for you from Ansible? Shouldn't the [*scope*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html#parameter-scope) of *systemd* be set to *user* too? The default is *system*.

Comment: I wrote something like this:
- name: set GOCRYPTFS_PASSWORD environment variable
  shell: |
    GOCRYPTFS_PASSWORD="{{ gocryptfs_password }}" systemctl import-environment GOCRYPTFS_PASSWORD --user
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  environment:
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: "{{ xdg_runtime_dir }}"
  become_user: "{{ gocryptfs_user }}"